# PHP - Using Stripos() to filter a String

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have read all thread about how to filter a string for certain needles and I think `stripos()` is what will do the job, however, the function does not return true when for example the first needle is found as if it is filtering the haystack using only the second value of my array.

**Example :**

```
$String = 'IWantToSolveThisProblem!!';
$needle = array('want', 'solve');

foreach ($needle as $value) {

$res = stripos($String, $value,0);
if($res !==false){

echo 'found';
}
else {
echo 'not found'; }}
```

In the example above the output will echo 'Found' because both values are present in my string.

The problem is that it is only using the last value of my array to loop. If the first value is present within the String and not the second it will return as false. 
I dont want to run multiple if statements

Comment: This code looks just fine. Are you sure that's the exact code that is not working for you?

Comment: Hi Jon, Yes i guess the code is fine.. I tried with two different needles and it worked well. I assume the problem is related whether the needle contains a numeric character. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @Raj see my answer. You'll lol @ yourself. You were correct, just simple mistakes. Go for a walk next time you are stuck like this :P

Comment: @brbcoding: Your answer doesn't really add anything. Especially the spaces part.

Comment: @Raj: That shouldn't make a difference either. In any case, unless you are able to provide code that actually does not work, we 're just wasting words.

Comment: @Jon, the semicolon is the only thing missing. The no spaces was more of an annoyance thing. And that is what I said in my answer, he/she was only missing the semi-colon.

Comment: @brbcoding: The question says "the text is not found, why?". I don't see how the semicolon could have anything to do with that, which is the point of my earlier comment. Obviously the OP's actual program does have the semicolon, otherwise they wouldn't be able to go far enough to ask this question.

Comment: @brbcoding - You are right the semicolon is missing here but i have the correct format in my code ( typing error) sorry for that and thx

Comment: @Jon, thanks for the advise. I will revise the scraper's code. I just needed to make sure I am on the right page.

Comment: What is the issue? Do you want the value to be "found" when giving $String the value 'IWantAnAnswer' ?

Comment: No, the issue is when having an array of multiple values, the looping seems to only take into the consideration the last value of my array and ignore in this case the first value. So when a String contains the first only would be false, on the other hand if both or last one are found it returns true.. I was curious to know if there's any parameter missing or my function is not properly declared. I guess the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Look at my answer. Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: I, like many others, do not understand your question.  Your code outputs 'foundfound', since both needles are present in your string.  When you add some debugging you find that all of the needles are looped past.

Answer (score 0):

```
$String = 'IWantToSolveThisProblem!!'; //you were missing this semicolon
$needle = array('want', 'solve'); //no spaces before the array (not needed, I just like nospaces :P)

foreach($needle as $value) {

$res = stripos($String, $value,0);
if($res !==false){

echo 'found';
}
else {
echo 'not found'; }}
```

*This doesn't make sense now... It's not that it's only comparing the last element. It just isn't comparing the first. See this example...*

```
$haystack = "string to be tested";
$needles  = array("string","to","pineapple","tested");
foreach($needles as $needle){
    if(stripos($haystack,$needle,0)){
        echo "The word \"$needle\" was found in the string \"$haystack\".";
    }
    else{
        echo "The word \"$needle\" was NOT found in the string \"$haystack\".";
    }
}

Expected Output:
The word "string" was found in the string "string to be tested".
The word "to" was found in the string "string to be tested".
The word "pineapple" was NOT found in the string "string to be tested".
The word "tested" was found in the string "string to be tested".

Actual Output:
The word "string" was NOT found in the string "string to be tested".
The word "to" was found in the string "string to be tested".
The word "pineapple" was NOT found in the string "string to be tested".
The word "tested" was found in the string "string to be tested".
```

*It all makes sense now... From the docs:*

> "This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function."

*So, changing* `if(stripos($haystack,$needle,0))` to `if(stripos($haystack,$needle,0) !== False)` *fixes the logic.*

```
$String = 'IWantToSolveThisProblem!!'; 
$needle = array('want', 'solve', 42); 

foreach($needle as $value) {

if(stripos($String, $value,0) !== FALSE){
    echo "found \"$value\" in \"$String \"";
}
else {
    echo "$value not found"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll also notice that the third param already defaults to 0 so you can skip that.  However this does not help the OP as they already have `!== false`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
if(stripos($value,$array[0]) !== false){ //check for the first element 
   echo "found want";
}
if(stripos($value,$array[1]) !== false){ //check for the second element
   echo "found solve";
}
```

Comment: If I run multiple if statements it will work but I don't think it is pratical for multiple values.
Isn't supposed the `Foreach` statement run each needle separately ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested with this code:

```
<?php
$str = "IWantToSolveThisProblem!";
$str2 = 'IWantAnAnswer';
$needles = array('want', 'solve');

foreach ($needles as $needle){
        $res = stripos($str2, $needle, 0);
        if ($res !== false){
                echo "$needle found\n";
        }
        else {
                echo "$needle not found\n";
        }
}
echo "\n";
?>
```

and it outputs:

```
$php testme.php

want found
solve not found
```

So it seems to work for me here... you might check for typos maybe..??!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$String = 'IWantToSolveThisProblem!!';
$needle = array('want', 'solve');

foreach ($needle as $value) {

$res = stripos($String, $value,0);
if($res !==false){

echo 'found';
}
else {
echo 'not found'; }}
?>
```

Output:
foundfound

If you "convert" your foreach-loop to if statements it would be the same as:

```
if(stripos($String,$needle[0]) !== false){ //check for the first element 
   echo "found";
}
if(stripos($String,$needle[1]) !== false){ //check for the second element
   echo "found";
}
```

Output:
foundfound

So the foreach - loop does several if-conditions (one for each element in the array)

Answer (score 0):

I've interpreted your question as a search to find a function that returns true when all needles are present in the given haystack, and here's a function that does just that...

```php
/**
 * Search the haystack for all of the given needles, returning true only if 
 * they are all present.
 * 
 * @param  string  $haystack  String to search
 * @param  array   $needles   Needles to look for
 * @return boolean            
 */
function stripos_array($haystack, array $needles)
{
    foreach ($needles as $needle)
    {
        if (stripos($haystack, $needle) === false) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// Test the function

$string = 'IWantToSolveThisProblem!!';

$search = array('want', 'solve');
$found = stripos_array($string, $search);
echo $found ? 'found' : 'not found', "\n"; // found

$search = array('want', 'cheese');
$found = stripos_array($string, $search);
echo $found ? 'found' : 'not found', "\n"; // not found

$search = array('cheese', 'problem');
$found = stripos_array($string, $search);
echo $found ? 'found' : 'not found', "\n"; // not found
```

---

It would be trivial to change this function to return true if any of the needles are found, instead of all needles.

```php
/**
 * Search the haystack for any of the given needles, returning true if any of
 * them are present.
 * 
 * @param  string  $haystack  String to search
 * @param  array   $needles   Needles to look for
 * @return boolean            
 */
function stripos_array($haystack, array $needles)
{
    foreach ($needles as $needle)
    {
        if (stripos($haystack, $needle) !== false) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are getting "not found" because when $value becomes "solve" it is not found in `$String = 'IWantAnAnswer'.`

Comment: The issue is why the looping is using the last array's value only.

Comment: When I ran the code above with the new string. I received two outputs.  "found" and "not found".  So, the loop uses both arrays.  Are you sure it's not using the first value of the array?

Comment: Yes, I switched values index 0 with index 1 and it is always looping with last value.